# How to efficiently gather the repeating elements in a given array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

I'd like to gather the duplicates in a given array. For example, i have an array like this:

```
{1,5,3,1,5,6,3}
```

and i want the result to be:

```
{3,3,1,1,5,5,6}
```

In my case, the number of cluster is unknowen before calculation, and the order is not concerned.

I achived this by using the bult-in function **Sort** in C++. However, actually the ordering is not necessary. Hence, i guess there are probably more efficient methods to accomplish it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just want to know how many of each elements in are in each group then this can be done O(n), histogram approach.  If you actually need to group the elements then I think you need to sort.

Comment: In what context do you need to do this? If this is something that's given as an assignment  in class, for example, it's likely that you are expected to use a particular technique that's been presented in class, and doing something else will likely fail your assignment.

Comment: You can do it in O(n) using hashing `std::unordered_map`, but in practice it would be more efficient for very big sizes only

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you, the example is a simplified version. In practice, i map a function to the elements and gather them by the results of the function.

Comment: @RichardCritten thank you for your reply, actually i don't have to know the number of elements in each group. In practice the elements are not gathered just by thier values, but the results of a function which is applied to them. Sort is a nice method, while i'm trying to seek a more efficient way.

Comment: @Damien Thank you for your reply, i'll try this. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, construct a histogram noting frequencies of each number. You can use a dictionary to accomplish this in O(n) time and space.

Next, loop over the dictionary's keys (order is unimportant here) and for each one, write a number of instances of that key equal to the corresponding value.

Example:

```
{1,5,3,1,5,6,3}                  input
{1->2,5->2,3->2,6->1}            histogram dictionary
{1,1,5,5,3,3,6}                  wrote two 1s, two 5s, two 3s, then one 6
```

This whole thing is O(n) time and space. Certainly you can't do better than O(n) time. Whether you can do better than O(n) space or not while maintaining O(n) time I cannot say.